# Child components not recognizing display grid in Angular

Tags: javascript, css, angular, grid, jsx

I have a `<app-body>` tag which is  like the main section of the app, above and below it I have a header  and a footer.
`<app-body>` is set to display: grid. It is split into 12 equally spaced columns. It’s css looks like this.

```
.app-body{
width: 100%;
min-height: calc(100vh - 150px); //150px is the height of the header footer and margins
overflow-y: scroll;
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);
}
```

I have `<app-article>` and an `<app-sidebar>` components inside it so it looks like this

```
<app-body class='app-body'>
  <app-article> </app-article>
  <app-sidebar> </app-sidebar>
</app-body>
```

`<app-article>` looks like this

```
<div class='article-body'>
  <p> jsfanasffanmslkjfdslakfsa lorem lorem lorem</p>
  <img src-'safdlsdkafjsdak>
</div>
```

and it’s css

```
.article-body{
grid-column: 1 / 8; 
}
```

It doesn’t work because it’s looking at the `<app-article>` tag for the columns. It can’t see the `.app-body.`
Any suggestions?